# node.js and browserify error

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

I am having difficulty setting up a node.js client to connect to a socket in java. the browser always give me this error

`Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`

and i used it in my html page

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        // open websocket

        var net = require('net');
        var socket = net.connect(8000, 'localhost');

    })
    </script>
```

i have installed node.js using `git clone https://github.com/joyent/node.git` and browserify  by `sudo npm install -g browserify`. i used `sudo` because it throws an `permission error` that i should execute the command with administrator level.

after installing browserify i am still getting the error in my browser

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

i understand my error i'am trying to import an nodejs to html which is not applicable. The next thing im doing is with browserify when i try to browserify index.js -o bundle.js it shows this error

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:906
      ret = Buffer.concat(list, length);
                   ^
TypeError: Object function Buffer(subject, encoding, offset) {
  if (!(this instanceof Buffer)) {
    return new Buffer(subject, encoding, offset);
  }

  var type;

  // Are we slicing?
  if (typeof offset === 'number') {
    this.length = coerce(encoding);
    this.parent = subject;
    this.offset = offset;
  } else {
    // Find the length
    switch (type = typeof subject) {
      case 'number':
        this.length = coerce(subject);
        break;

      case 'string':
        this.length = Buffer.byteLength(subject, encoding);
        break;

      case 'object': // Assume object is an array
        this.length = coerce(subject.length);
        break;

      default:
        throw new Error('First argument needs to be a number, ' +
                        'array or string.');
    }

    if (this.length > Buffer.poolSize) {
      // Big buffer, just alloc one.
      this.parent = new SlowBuffer(this.length);
      this.offset = 0;

    } else {
      // Small buffer.
      if (!pool || pool.length - pool.used < this.length) allocPool();
      this.parent = pool;
      this.offset = pool.used;
      pool.used += this.length;
    }

    // Treat array-ish objects as a byte array.
    if (isArrayIsh(subject)) {
      for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        this.parent[i + this.offset] = subject[i];
      }
    } else if (type == 'string') {
      // We are a string
      this.length = this.write(subject, 0, encoding);
    }
  }

  SlowBuffer.makeFastBuffer(this.parent, this, this.offset, this.length);
} has no method 'concat'
    at fromList (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:906:20)
    at Transform.read (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:373:11)
    at flow (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:629:52)
    at Array.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/browserify/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:600:7)
    at EventEmitter._tickCallback (node.js:190:38)
```

is this error with browserify? example of my nodejs

`server.js`

```
var http = require("http");
var url = require("url");

function start(route) {
  function onRequest(request, response) {
    var pathname = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
    console.log("Request for " + pathname + " received.");

    route(pathname);

    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("Hello World");
    response.end();
  }

  http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
  console.log("Server has started.");
}

exports.start = start;
```

`router.js`

```
function route(pathname) {
  console.log("About to route a request for " + pathname);
}
exports.route = route;
```

`index.js`

```
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router");

server.start(router.route);
```

[this](http://www.nodebeginner.org/) is my reference.

Comment: Browserify does not let you make sockets, even if you actually include it in your page.

Comment: what i mean is that it says if i installed browserify it will let me use the `require` function @SLaks

Comment: Read the documentation on how to use Browserify, just installing it won't do anything. You have to create a bundle to include in the browser.

Comment: Also, what you're trying to do is completely impossible.  You need to learn more about how browser Javascript works, then read about web sockets.

Comment: i just read this [link](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/net.html)

Comment: What is your node version?

Comment: nodejs v0.10.31 @3y3

Answer (score 0):

You've missed a major step in the browserify workflow. What browserify does is transform your javascript from works-in-node to works-in-the-browser, and that requires actually running the `browserify` command line tool on your javascript, which will generate for you a new javascript file (the "bundle"), which you can then reference in your `<script>` tag, load into the browser, and have work correctly. Go through a tutorial again and pay attention to that step.

Comment: i have seen some tutorials but i dont know where to put `browserify ./x.js > main.js` line of code and i dont know what does `x.js` should containt. could you give me a snippet? @PeterLyons

Comment: Take all the code you have inline in your `<script>` tag and put it in a file called `x.js`. You'll need to not use the `net` core module as that doesn't work in browsers, but the point is just have `<script src="/main.js"></script>` in your HTML and use browserify on the command line to generate `main.js` from you application's entrypoint `x.js` file.

Comment: thanks but when i try to generate main.js i got the error above. i use `browserify x.js -o main.js`